# Python: how to train the same model different times?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I have a small dataset and I want to try to predict the value of same variables using the `Multi-layer Perceptron regressor` from `sklearn`.

This is what I am doing:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y)
scaler  = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test  = scaler.transform(X_test)

mlp    = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(10,10))
mlp    = mlp.fit(X_train,y_train)
test_y = mlp.predict(X_test)
```

Now the training set is composed by `100` examples. What I would like to to do is to split the training set four times in `75` and `25` in order to train the same model with `4` different dataset.

This what I am doing:

```
c1 = 0
c2 = 25
for i in range(0,4):
    xt = X_train[c1:c2]
    yt = np.setdiff1d(X_train, xt)
    c1 = c2 + 1
    c2 = c2 + 25
    mlp = mlp.fit(xt ,yt)
```

Comment: Are you talking about cross-validation? Then see [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) description for some relevant functions in sklearn.

Comment: Yes I am, please have a look to the modified code.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: @UmangGupta the problems: am I a training the same model four times or not?

Answer (score 0):

you should be getting an error because you are accessing the `X_train` out of its bounds in the last iteration. That is of course, given that `X_train` has only 100 samples.

Accessing an array in the following form `myArray[a:b]` mean that I want to retrieve the elements starting from `a` up to but not including `b`.

As a result, you need to change this line:

`c1 = c2 + 1`

to this one:

`c1 = c2`

Have a look on the [documentation](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html) to know how to access a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

# Generate some random data
X = np.random.rand(100,5)
Y = np.dot(X, np.random.rand(5))+np.random.rand(100)

# Split into train and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y)

# Use 4 fold cross validation on train data
cv_results = cross_validate(MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(10,10)), X_train, y_train, cv=4, 
                            scoring=('neg_mean_squared_error'), return_estimator=True)
print (cv_results['test_score'])

# Make predictions on test data
y = np.zeros(len(y_test))
for i, model in enumerate(cv_results['estimator']):
    y_hat = model.predict(X_test)
    print ("Model {0} MSE Error: {1}".format(i, 
        mean_squared_error(y_test, y_hat)))
    y += y_hat

print ("Average Test MSE Error: {0}".format(
        mean_squared_error(y_test, y/len(models))))
```

Code is explained in the comments. We split the data into train and hidden test data. We do CV on train data for 4 fold. It is represented in below diagram.

[image]